# How to type hexadecimal into binary using DOS Interrupt in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, hardware, x86-16

following code is including a hexadecimal number  (relevant to ASCII code assume that it is obtained from keyboard), I want to print  this hex number to the screen but in "binary" using DOS Interrupt. 
NUMLOCK is 45h.

```
[org 0x0100]
     mov AL, 45     ;moving NUMLOCK hexadecimal(ASCII code) to AX
     ~~How to display its binary relevant to screen using DOS Interrupt?
```

Comment: Not sure what your assembler is and how it does compile, but mine will from `mov al,45` compile instruction which will load into `al` (not `ax`) value `45` (not `69`). (`45h == 69` if you by accident missed where the `69` came from). What your comment says would be `mov ax,69` or `mov ax,45h` or `mov ax,0b01000101` if your Assembler supports binary formatting in source. Either way the resulting machine code for 8086 will be `b8 45 00`, formatting of source doesn't matter.

Comment: And I forgot one more thing. And `0x45` in ASCII is `'E'`, not numlock. `0x45` is "numlock" in keyboard scancodes (when you read the scancodes directly from BIOS interrupt or keyboard device, before they get converted into ASCII characters). "Numlock" does not have any ASCII character assigned, it's special IBM PC key, which does alter behaviour of keyboard reading, while ASCII was first wide spread 7 bit alphabet encoding, before ASCII basically every computer did encode strings a bit differently.

Comment: is there any short command that will just show binary equavalent on screen? using dos interrupt?

Comment: DOS interrupts can only display characters and character strings.

Comment: how to convert the assci hexa code into binary and then give binary as a string to dos interrupt to print on screen?

Comment: In you code `45` is a decimal number. `45h` or `0x45` etc. (depending on asm syntax) woud be hex. Computer memory and registers store binary numbers, not decimal (except in rare cases) or hexadecimal. In a way, they *do* store hexa, but that is really just a humanly convenient way of grouping binary digits (bits) into sets of 4, so the brain can more easily understand them.

Comment: You don't have ascii hexa in your code. Ascii hexa is in your source. Assembler does compile it into binary value. If you want ASCII hexa value in your code, you must write it like `db '4', '5', 'h'` = there, these three bytes form ASCII hexa value. When you do `db 45h`, the Assembler will parse and convert the string into numeric integer, binary encoded in bits as value `69`.  In other words, you are mixing wrong terms together... take some time to re-read the courses/lessons to understand what is what.

Answer (score 4):

DOS Interrupt has only these services outputting to screen:

[AH = 02h -WRITE CHARACTER TO STANDARD OUTPUT](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah02)
[AH = 06h - DIRECT CONSOLE OUTPUT](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah06)
[AH = 09h - WRITE STRING TO STANDARD OUTPUT](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah09)
[AH = 40h - "WRITE" - WRITE TO FILE OR DEVICE](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah40) (when called with STDOUT or STDERR file handle)

All of these only copy the value from input to the output, without any conversions or formatting, so usually your input should be ASCII character or string, or binary byte array.

But you should understand, that computers work in binary (low current/high current, which is often interpreted as 0 or 1). It doesn't understand any other value.

So when you have value `69` in CPU register `al`, the `al` is created from 8 bit cells on the CPU chip, and those cells are set as "0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1". The cells are called bits. So when you write in Assembly source `mov al,45h`, the assembler during compilation creates this binary form for you, and stores it into machine code as single byte, because that's how `mov al,imm8` instruction expects the value encoded.

So all you have to do for "binary string" is to go bit by bit from left to right, 8 times, and output character `'0'` or `'1'` to the screen, depending whether particular bit is clear, or set.

If your task would be to display the number in any other base (for example base 10 = decimal), you would have to do complex calculation to find out particular digits `'6'` and `'9'` forming the decimal format "69".

Any base of power of two is a bit simpler, because you need just to extract group of bits (for example in hexadecimal base 16 every single digit is exactly 4 bits part of value, notice how `45h` is in binary `0100` (4) and `0101` (5). But you still have to calculate groups of bits.

Only the binary base 2 output is basically ready to be printed, because that's the native way how computer stores numerical integer values in registers and memory.

It's absolutely crucial you realize what are bits, and what does it mean that `al` is 8 bit register, and `ax` is 16 bit register, and `ah` is upper 8 bits of `ax`, etc... If you don't understand how binary math works, and how those values are encoded in bits, you will have hard time with very simple Assembly tasks, like this one.

That's why I'm not even adding any code here, because you need first work out your math, to fully understand what ["base N" encoding of value](https://betterexplained.com/articles/numbers-and-bases/) means.

After you will understand what the computer does work with, you will be very likely able to quickly check some bit-wise instructions like shifts or test, and do the bit check + output 0/1 to screen loop. It's very simple task, when you understand it.

---

EDIT: I decided to give you something more visual, I wrote "display binary 8 bit value" in the "Simple 8-bit Assembler".

It's not 8086, but:

- the instructions are "same" (just very limited set, not full 8086)
- registers completely different (four 8 bit general purpose A, B, C, D and two specialized PC and SP pointers)
- memory layout completely different (only 256 bytes of total memory, last 24 bytes are for "output" display)
- the principles are same, if you understand this one, 8086 will look much more easier, just lot more powerful and easier to code (more instructions).

Put the next code into page: http://schweigi.github.io/assembler-simulator/

And use "Step" to slowly go instruction by instruction and watch the "memory" and "register" views on right to see, what the instruction does (you can use x86 instruction reference guide to read what the instruction should do, I think all the descriptions will fit also this simple Assembler (although some are not 100% correct about flags, but you will not notice and better learn 8086 instructions from start)).

```
    ; init input values
    MOV     A, 0x45 ; A = 45h (this ASM needs "0x" for hexa)
    MOV     D, 240  ; point to output display after last digit
    MOV     C, 8    ; 8 chars (representing bits) to output

print_loop:

    ; convert lowest bit of A into ASCII digit '0' or '1'
    MOV     B, A    ; copy of A (to preserve A value)
    AND     B, 1    ; extract lowest bit of A (B = 0 or 1)
    ADD     B, '0'  ; turn the value 0/1 into ASCII '0'/'1'

    ; display '0' or '1' to "Output" window
    MOV     [D], B  ; write the digit to output
    DEC     D       ; update output pointer

    ; shift all bits in A to right by 1 position
    SHR     A, 1

    ; create space after 4 bits displayed 
    CMP     C, 5    ; 8-3 = 5, fourth DEC is below (in future)
    JNE     .no_space
    DEC     D       ; skip one position in output
.no_space:

    ; loop until 8 bits are displayed
    DEC     C       ; counter of bits
    JNZ     print_loop  ; repeat until C becomes 0

    ; stop simulator
    HLT
```

Then you can think how you can turn this into 8086 version.

I would suggest to turn the loop logic to go from top-most bit, it's easier with 8086, as you can use many more instructions, like `adc` (for example you can try to figure out, what is result of `mov dl,24` `adc dl,dl` ... it may be quite interesting after `shl`). Then you can output the digits directly by `int 21h,2` (if you reverse the logic to test bits from left to right).

Or you can keep the same logic, and store the ASCII digits into memory buffer from end (make sure you have big enough buffer), and the print it with single `int 21h, 9`.

Or ... there are million other ways how to calculate the same result (outputting to screen "0100 0101" ASCII digits from original value `45h`). It's only about outputting correct number at correct place and time, how you calculate it doesn't matter, as long as your result is correct.

Comment: is there anyway to just pickup the 8bits  without conversion because computer also works on binary so why should we reconvert it? why we cannot directly access the stored binary of character and display on screen?

Comment: @HareemFatima yes, but no. If you understand the value already is binary, that is good. And you *can* put it directly at screen without conversion. The problem is, that the screen does not display values as numbers, for example in 24b RGB graphics mode one byte value becomes one red/green/blue subpixel intensity. So if you put `45h` at first byte of such RGB display with 0 elsewhere, it will display ~25% blue (or red). In DOS in EGA/VGA text mode you can write the value direction to `B800:0000`, and it will become character 'E' on screen, because text modes work in ASCII.

Comment: @HareemFatima for DOS textmodes you have to convert those bits into stream of values 48 (digit "0" in ASCII) and 49 ("1"). Please, please, try that 8 bit assembly simulator, and watch how these two values are written at the end of memory space (addresses 232 to 240), and how at right top there's "display displaying the values from memory as ASCII chars"... this is super close to the real [PC text mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-compatible_text_mode) but PC does store two bytes, color+ASCII, so to show "0" in white color on green background write at B800:0000 WORD `0x2F30`

Comment: @HareemFatima you can try at start of your code to do `mov ax,0B800h` `mov es,ax` `mov ax,2F30h` `es:mov [160*10+6*2],ax` (you didn't even write which assembler you use, so adjust syntax to your assembler, I tried to use the most universal, which maybe will work in most of them) - This will put digit "0" in white/green at 11th line and 7th column. (without calling `int 21h` or `int 10h`, directly writing value into video memory). (hm, NASM will understand only `mov     [es:160*10+6*2],ax` variant. TASM maybe `mov     es:[160*10+6*2],ax`) (NASM v2: `es mov  [160*10+6*2],ax` works too)

Comment: @HareemFatima let me know, if you did try A) the simple 8-bit assembler web page B) the above mentioned `mov` into video ram ... and if it did work for you. But the A) should help you to *SEE* what is happening in computer. Play with it for a while, try to understand what is what and how it works, also there are different options like hex <-> decimal of memory values, etc... This is IMO one of best tools, if you are "visual" type of person, it can hardly be easier than this, to explain how CPU and computer works. + get together with some other student, so you can go over these answers in pair.